# What's the difference between the CakePHP 2.x Plugin and plugins folders?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

From CakePHP 2.0 on, the folder structure is like this:

-- MyApplicationName
--- app
---- **Plugin**
---- (other folders ...)
--- lib
--- **plugins**
--- vendors

Is there any difference between the *Plugin*-folder within the app-folder or the *plugins*-folder within the application root folder?

What's the recommended use of those folders? Or can you use them as you wish?

*Sorry if this is a recurrent question, but a quick search didn't provide me any similar questions...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe it matters. I think the main reason that there was a folder outside the app folder, was so that it could be shared among different sites (like the core files).

So, use your own discretion.

Comment: exactly - I use the Plugin folder for app specific plugins and the root one for "global" plugins like "Tools" etc. But there is a discussion about removing the root plugin folder maybe in some upcoming cake version. so if you are uncertain you will be better off using the app one!